# Pandas transpose column to row

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
DATE     NAME    INCOME   EXPENSE
201811    XX      100      50
```

I need it transposed (long format) like this:

```
DATE     NAME    ATTRIBUTE  ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
201811    XX      INCOME      100
201811    XX      EXPENSE      50
```

I looked at the pandas transpose function but I am not sure how to go from wide format to long format

Comment: Can you post how you want the output dataframe to look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
pd.melt(df1,id_vars=['DATE','NAME'],var_name='ATTRIBUTE',value_name='ATTRIBUTE_VALUE')

     DATE NAME ATTRIBUTE  ATTRIBUTE_VALUE
0  201811   XX    INCOME              100
1  201811   XX   EXPENSE               50
```